# Compare Images For A Catalog - Php

Tags: php, mysql, image, compare, catalog

I am creating a jewellery catalogue. I am looking to find a way to compare images so that I don't end up uploading the product images again and again.

For this purpose I am using [Image-Compare](https://github.com/inceddy/ImageCompare) for Php.
The catalogue will be containing 100s and even 1000s of images so it is not feasible to "Compare the mean-color of all areas and the area count" of each image against each other every time at the time of upload.

I am trying a way to store that "the mean-color of all areas and the area count" of each image in the database itself so that it is easier and faster to compare. Using the difference method returns a float between 0 and 1, where 1 is equal and 0 is total difference.

Comment: perhaps the `sha1_file` function might be of use?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius later, how to use the returned value to compare similarity between the images?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good image comparator package with good documentation
https://github.com/sapientpro/image-comparator

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.